# rpmbuild: how to build the package without %install?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I am trying to build a rpm but unfortunately in my build machine I only have limted permission, which means the operation in %install can't be done inside the build machine. How to build the package(.rpm file) without running %install section? It looks like that no options are available for this purpose:

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/ch-rpm-b-command.html

My bu.spec file:

```
Summary: xxxx
Name: xx
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
Group: Applications/Sound
License: Share

%description

%prep
echo "prep"

%build

%install
echo "install"
mkdir -p /opt/xcp_src/
cp scripts.tgz /opt/xcp_src/

%files
/tmp/xcp_src/scripts.tgz

%post
cd /opt/xcp_src/
tar zxvf scripts.tgz
```

Comment: Is the code you give representative of the spec file?

Comment: Is this your own program, or are you just trying to package something? If the latter, then it is not programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, set a [buildroot](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-anywhere.html) and use that in install, eg:

```
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root
...
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt/xcp_src
```

Second, make sure you can build without being root by [moving the RPM build area](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html).

I'd also suggest specifying an actual list of files (rather than having RPM extract a tgz file) as that would make the package cleanly removable.

Comment: ...and thats what buildroot is for